# Neo4j cypher liking a status update

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to implement a liking mechanism to the the demo newsfeed shown here http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html

So basically when a user clicks like on a status update I want to link the user node to the status update node. However I want to search for the status update node through the author's node. Hence I use something like the following:

```
MATCH (n:user)-[:STATUSUPDATE]->(m)-[:NEXT*]->(o)
WHERE n.username = "pewpewlasers" AND (m.permalink = "acode" OR o.permalink = "acode")
MATCH (p:user)
WHERE id(p)=1,
CREATE (p)-[x:LIKED]->(o)
return x
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is, finding a status update node through the **author**'s node, and then looking for the update with a permalink code.

When found I want to connect the **liker** user's node to the status update through a `LIKED` relationship.

However, you probably already see the problems with this cypher.

This cypher requires that the permalink is one of the nodes that is connected with `NEXT` relationship, otherwise if the first node (connected by the `STATUSUPDATE` relationship) contains the permalink, it selects all status update nodes connected by the `NEXT` relationship. The user will thus end up liking all posts. What is probably required is like the following:

```
MATCH (n:user)-[:STATUSUPDATE]->(m)-[:NEXT*]->(o)
WHERE n.username = "pewpewlasers" AND m.permalink = "acode"
-- IF THE ABOVE GIVES AN OUTPUT THEN --
   MATCH (p:user)
   WHERE id(p)=1,
   CREATE (p)-[x:LIKED]->(m)
   return x
-- ELSE --
   MATCH (n:user)-[:STATUSUPDATE]->(m)-[:NEXT*]->(o)
   WHERE n.username = "pewpewlasers" AND o.permalink = "acode"
   MATCH (p:user)
   WHERE id(p)=1,
   CREATE (p)-[x:LIKED]->(o)
   return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get around your problem.

```
START p = node(1) // Do you really want to use node numbers?    
MATCH (n:user {username = 'pewpewlasers'})-[:STATUSUPDATE|:NEXT*]->(m {permalink : 'acode'})
CREATE (p)-[x:LIKED]->(m)
```

By using the '|' and multimatch in the relationship part of the MATCH clause, the 'm' node is able to match any part of the status update chain. If you really are going to use node numbers (the output of the 'id()' function) to get your liking user node, it's probably faster to do it as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, this works. And I have changed the code so that it uses the username and not the node numbers. One more question though. Is it possible to check if the user has already liked the status update before we implement `CREATE (p)-[x:LIKED]->(m)`?